# Magento 2: Some products are out of stock

Tags: magento2.3, stock, out-of-stock

I don't understand why some products are **`out of stock`** (they have quantity and are in stock).
I imported an csv with all products. For some products the price is shown (they are in stock) and for some products is shown **`out of stock`**. I checked and is no difference (in admin and csv). I also checked orders and that products are not ordered.

[image]

[image]

Comment: import csv after run reindex commands ?

Comment: I ran bin/magento index:reindex many times. But, nothing change.

Comment: Hey, you can check at store level too not just in default don't know if you did, but it's strange and without checking the admin it's hard to help too. Would help if you could create a user that can access only the products, but I know many times isn't possible to do it.